# plural or not: 'the incidences of' VS 'the incidence of'

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. The incidences of limb loss **are** increasing and as a consequence also the need for prosthetic devices.
> 2. The incidence of limb loss **is** increasing and as a consequence also the need for prosthetic devices.

Which one to choose?

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence is correct.

The meaning of [incidence](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/incidence) is:

> an event, or the rate at which something happens

Since you are talking about a single metric (limb loss), not multiple metrics, using "*The incidences of*" is wrong and you should use **"The incidence of"**.

Here is an example for **the incidences of**:

> The increased incidences of cancers, heart attacks and liver diseases

Comment: I agree that it works better as a rate (singular), but I thing that **wrong** is going a bit too far. for the plural version. Can you explain why you think that the **an event** part of the definition that you quote does not sanction the use of "the incidences of.."? You could, for example, say "muggings are increasing", even though mugging is not a rate.

Comment: @JavaLatte Sorry, I'm not sure if have understood your point correctly. Can we use "*the incidences of*" for one metric? (metric here does not point to a singular noun, what I'm trying to say is that we can have "*the increased incidence of car accidents*", but this is not true about "*the increased incidences of car accidents*" and it should be followed by at least one other metric. For example: "*the increased incidences of car accidents and airplane crashes*". Don't you think so?

Comment: As the definition says, "incidence" can be an event or a rate (a metric, as you call it). "car accident" is countable, so you can simply say "car accidents are increasing". "Limb loss" can be countable "limb losses are increasing", but most people would regard it as uncountable: to talk about a plural, you add "incidences" and say "incidences of limb loss are increasing".  See the first example in the Cambridge dictionary that you provided a link to, where "bullying" is uncountable: "There have been quite a few incidences of bullying in the school this year."